# Asynchronous handling of messages - which concurrency primitives to use?

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, asynchronous

I am building a simple implementation of the PostgreSQL wire protocol, and want the client to send messages to my service, and then process them asynchronously in the background. I am having a little trouble understanding when to use an `ExecutorService` versus using raw threads. I am using two `BlockingQueue`s - one to put the messages on and have them sent to the server, and one to receive messages into, my code so far is below.

What I want to know is, does it make sense to use an ExecutorService here or should I just create and start `ReceiveThread` and `SendThread` as standalone threads (i.e. `new Thread(new ReceiveThread()).start();`)?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class Connection {

    private MessageBuilder builder;
    private MessageReader reader;

    private BlockingQueue<byte[]> sendQueue;
    private BlockingQueue<byte[]> receiveQueue;

    private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    private Socket socket;

    public Connection(String hostName, int port, String username) throws IOException {
        this(new MessageBuilder(), new MessageReader(), hostName, port, username);
    }

    public Connection(MessageBuilder builder, MessageReader reader, String hostName, int port, String username) throws IOException {
        this.builder = builder;
        this.reader = reader;
        this.sendQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<byte[]>();
        this.receiveQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<byte[]>();
        socket = new Socket(hostName, port);
        List<Param> params = new ArrayList<Param>();
        params.add(new Param("user", username));
        sendQueue.add(builder.buildStartupMessage(3, 0, params));

        exec.submit(new SendThread(sendQueue, new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())));
        exec.submit(new ReceiveThread(receiveQueue, new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()), new MessageReader()));
    }

    public void sendMessage(byte[] bytes) {
        sendQueue.add(bytes);
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws IOException {
        socket.close();
    }
}

class ReceiveThread implements Callable<Boolean> {
    private BlockingQueue<byte[]> receiveQueue;
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private MessageReader reader;

    public ReceiveThread(BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue, DataInputStream dis, MessageReader reader) {
        this.receiveQueue = queue;
        this.dis = dis;
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        byte msgByte = dis.readByte();
        System.out.println("Response type is: " + (char) msgByte);
        int length = dis.readInt();
        byte[] message = new byte[length+1];
        message[0] = msgByte;
        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(length).array();
        System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, message, 1, bytes.length);
        int readLength = dis.read(message, 5, length - 5 );
        System.out.println("readLength : " + readLength + " should be length: " + (length-5));
        receiveQueue.put(message);
        return true;
    }
}

class SendThread implements Callable<Boolean> {

    private BlockingQueue<byte[]> sendQueue;
    private DataOutputStream dos;

    public SendThread(BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue, DataOutputStream dos) {
        this.sendQueue = queue;
        this.dos = dos;
    }

    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        byte[] message = sendQueue.take();
        dos.write(message);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit of using the `ExecutorService` is that it provides thread pooling. If you have many short-lived threads, the overhead caused by the creation of these threads may be significant. ExecutorService can take care of that by working with a thread pool, and assigning threads to your tasks. It also takes care of scheduling. Say, you have 15000 jobs to do, each takes 5ms to complete. Creating 15000 threads would obviously not make sense. The `ExecutorService` will schedule your jobs on, say, 4 threads. You can use different types of `ExecutorService`s depending on your needs.

I don't completely understand in your code, why you are not using loops in send and receive threads. Your code will receive/send only one message which I don't think is your intention. You could get rid of the `ExecutorService` and have 2 long-lived threads, one for sending, one for receiving (as you currently have). Inside these, however, you should write a while loop which periodically checks for the content of the queues.